# Phonegap Android App "App not installed"

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I just try to create a Android project from the existing code in Eclipse. Everything seems fine without error prompt. Also I can test it in virtual device. So I tried to create a apk by exported unsigned application package. Finally the app cannot be installed to my android and it just prompt the "App not installed" message! How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take apk from bin folder and try to install it on device...not from create apk by exported unsigned package.make sure you have sufficient internal memory (that should be more than just the app size, because app needs to store data too).

Comment: what bin folder? i only have the apk generated by phonegap build

Comment: It works if you take from bin folder but does not if you build through phone-gap site.

Comment: there was not enough memory. Thanks!

Comment: as far as I can see, unsigned apks created with `--release` cannot never be installed on a device. debug builds instead are allowed. if you want to install a release build, you'll need to sign it, point.

Answer (score 19):

I was facing the same error using `cordova build --release android` from CLI to create apk but later on found that `cordova build android` should be used to create debug apk file.Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 5):

I was also getting this issue, despite using `cordova build android`. Turns out my problem was the following:

I previously installed another phonegap app, which I built, without changing its widget id in config.xml. So the widget id remained "com.phonegap.helloworld".

Now, when building my new app, I also did not change the widget id. So both apps have the same widget id. This, it appears, is not allowed. So one potential solution is changing the widget id, so it does not interfere with anything else currently installed on your phone. Or, uninstall whatever your new app may be interfering with (perhaps some phonegap app you made earlier, as in my case).

Here's what led me to this solution:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/922

Comment: another app with the same widget id is easy to forget when you are working on different projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you update/overwrite an existing app, first remove it with the application manager of your phone.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have sufficient internal memory (that should be more than just the app size, because app needs to store data too). The storage for apps is different from internal mass storage. You can find it under Settings > Storage, look for the Applications label.

Also, if the app is, say 20 MB, keep at least 50 MB free, because apart from the app storage, Android also tends to slow down when short on internal memory.

If you're trying to update/overwrite an installed app, try removing it first.

Thanks
AB

Comment: Thanks. The app is quite small, only 2.2MB size. I believe the device has good enough memory to running it.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth...
I started getting "app not installed" after I had created a guest account, for whatever reason.  Deleting the guest account seems to have solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You can ONLY install signed apps on an Android device. In fact, a debug version of an application is signed with a debug key. That means you have to sign your release app. Even if you just try to install it locally on your smartphone.

1. Uninstall some other version of the application.
2. You will need to generate your my-release-key.keystore file with keytool:

   keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name
   -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
3. Cordova has a built-in way to let you sign Android apps quickly. Sign your App when deploying it through the CLI.

   cordova run android --release -- --keystore=my-release-key.keystore
   --storePassword=password --alias=alias_name --password=password --packageType=apk

Now you should have your final product: app-release.apk

*You can use --packageType=bundle to export it like .aab

*Alternatively, you could specify them in a build configuration file (build.json): https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/#using-buildjson

```
{
    "android": {
        "debug": {
            "keystore": "../android.keystore",
            "storePassword": "android",
            "alias": "mykey1",
            "password" : "password",
            "keystoreType": "",
            "packageType": "apk"
        },
        "release": {
            "keystore": "../android.keystore",
            "storePassword": "",
            "alias": "mykey2",
            "password" : "password",
            "keystoreType": "",
            "packageType": "bundle"
        }
    }
}
```